# Android ScrollView - ensure that it is always larger than the screen size?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview with multiple different views inside of it. What I want is to have all the elements of the scrollview EXCEPT the last element fill the whole screen. The user can then scroll down to reveal the last item in the scrollview. I do not want that last item to be visible in any other case.

My XML looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.45"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View 1 ... android:weight="2.25" />
        <View 2 ... android:weight="0.8" />
        <View 3 ... android:weight="0.40" /> //last item
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What this currently does is completely fill the whole screen, but does not have the last item push off.

Comment: you can set height for your two first views dynamically,get device height and set it for that maybe 50% for first ,50% for second .but I suggest you do this purpose in other way

Comment: do not mix `fill_parent` and `match_parent` in your code. `fill_parent` has been deprecated and should not be used

Comment: hmm behavior seems odd, perhaps you want a sliding drawer from the bottom? https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the last post(now deleted),You should place the last item outside LinearLayout group or in a different LinearLayout.
It will be smth like

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"<!-- added-->
    android:layout_height="match_parent"><!-- added-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:oriention="vertical"><!-- added-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/visible_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"><!-- changed-->
            ...{items}
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            {last item}
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

UPDATE: now you need to extend height of linearLayout to fill screen:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.visible_items);
LayoutParams lp = layout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = point.y;
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

NOTE: put above code in onWindowFocusChanged() methos of activity

Comment: This worked like a charm, but I needed to do a few more things (for my situation). I have an actionbar AND a static footer that is at the bottom of the screen and is visible at all times (ie not part of the scrollview). So, I did this: `lp.height = point.y - getActionBar().getHeight() - statusbarHeight;`

Comment: happy for help you :)